# Dplyr - First Value that fulfills Condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this dataframe

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tribble(
    ~a, ~b, ~c
    , 1, 1, 1
    , 1, 0, 2
    , 1, 0, 3
    , 2, 0, 1
    , 2, 1, 2
    , 2, 1, 3
)
```

and I want to add a column `d` contains grouped by `a` the first value of `c` that fulfills the condition `b == 1`, like so...

```
tribble(
    ~a, ~b, ~c, ~d
    , 1, 1, 1, 1
    , 1, 0, 2, 1
    , 1, 0, 3, 1
    , 2, 0, 1, 2
    , 2, 1, 2, 2
    , 2, 1, 3, 2
)
```

How can I do that? (ideally using `dplyr`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution using `first`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(a) %>%
  mutate(d = first(c[b==1])) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Great thanks - don't why I didn't think of a mixing between dplyr and base.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `match` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(d = c[match(1, b)])

#      a     b     c     d
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1     1     1
#2     1     0     2     1
#3     1     0     3     1
#4     2     0     1     2
#5     2     1     2     2
#6     2     1     3     2
```

Or with `which.max` :

```
df %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(d = c[which.max(b == 1)])
#Safer using which
#df %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(d = c[which(b == 1)[1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

An option is

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     group_by(a) %>%
     mutate(d = c[b == 1][1])
```